# Could not resolve the signature of a virtual method - Xamarin forms - Shiny.SpeechRecognition

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am trying to integrate the Shiny.SpeechRecognition package into my xam.forms proj.
What i have did so far....

1. Created a new xam.forms proj
2. Updated all NuGet package to latest
3. Installed Shiny.SpeechRecognition

After this point, i got an error saying =>

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error     Can not resolve reference: `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions`,
> referenced by `System.Reactive`. Please add a NuGet package or
> assembly reference for `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions`, or remove
> the reference to `System.Reactive`.   ShinySpeechRecog.Android

I found a workaround for this from AllanRitchie's Blog as this was a bug in VS-2017

4. created a startup class in my PCL proj

Here is the class..

```
public class MyStartup : ShinyStartup
{
    public override void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.UseSpeechRecognition();
    }
}
```

5. Next created an application class as instructed in shiny docs

the code here....

```
[Application]
public class MyApplication : Shiny.ShinyAndroidApplication<MyStartup>
{
    public MyApplication(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(handle, transfer)
    {

    }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        Shiny.AndroidShinyHost.Init(
            this, new MyStartup());
        base.OnCreate();
    }
}
```

6. Then in MainActivity

like this...

```
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Permission[] grantResults)
{
    AndroidShinyHost.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

7. For IOS AppDelegate

this one..

```
Shiny.iOSShinyHost.Init(new MyStartup());
```

8. Finally in my MainPage UI

this button click event handler

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Shiny.AccessState granted = await Shiny.ShinySpeechRecognizer.RequestAccess();
    //Did you notice the line above?? It is different from the one i saw in the shiny docs..
    if (granted == Shiny.AccessState.Available)
        await DisplayAlert("Success", "Shiny Speech Recog is working", "Ok");
}
```

Now at this point, app builds without error however i see a warning as below

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Warning   NU1605  Detected package downgrade:
> System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions from 4.5.4 to 4.0.0. Reference the
> package directly from the project to select a different version.
> ShinySpeechRecog.Android -> Shiny.SpeechRecognition 1.2.0.1755 ->
> Shiny.Core 1.2.0.1755 -> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
> 3.1.5 -> Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces 1.1.1 -> System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions (>= 4.5.4)
> ShinySpeechRecog.Android -> System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions (>=
> 4.0.0)    ShinySpeechRecog.Android    C:\Users\S3 User1\source\repos\ShinySpeechRecog\ShinySpeechRecog\ShinySpeechRecog.Android\ShinySpeechRecog.Android.csproj   1

But when I run the app, this error pops out and app closes

> Could not resolve the signature of a virtual method - Xamarin forms -
> Shiny.SpeechRecognition

POSTING SO FAR RESEARCHED LINKS FOR USE:

https://github.com/aritchie/speechrecognition

https://github.com/shinyorg/shiny

https://shinydocs.azurewebsites.net/docs/gettingstarted

https://shinydocs.azurewebsites.net/docs/extras/speechrecognition

https://github.com/shinyorg/ShinySamples (Incase you need the samples)

https://allancritchie.net/posts/introducingshiny (the big daddy)

Comment: Ok.. I cant solve this err... I just used another code for speech to text.. Thats working fine..

Comment: Hi , if have solved that , remember to share the solution in answer when you have time :-)

Comment: sure @JuniorJiang-MSFT , umm I'll try to post it today..

Comment: HI @JuniorJiang-MSFT, I have posted the anser, can you help me in the issue i am facing..?

Comment: Okey , thanks for sharing . I will check that , if good news will update there :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to use the shiny plugin for voice search in my xamarin.forms. So after some time i came accross this link..

https://medium.com/@dev.aritradas/xamarin-forms-speech-recognition-c16f07cdf164

The above links will help us to implement the voice search using the built in support for speech sdks from android and iOS using Dependency Service in xamarin forms. The above plugin additionally uses CurrentActivityPlugin by James Montemagno.

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin

I have tried this and it is working fine in my application. But i am facing one small problem here. The problem is, I have implemented this voice search feature in 3 content pages of a tabbed page, so what happens here is, When I perform the voice search in one page, the resultant words extracted from the speech are shared also to the other two content pages and the list view in all pages gets updated. Since I am new to Xamarin forms and dependency service, Messaging center, android - current activity.. I need some help to solve this issue..

Comment: Haa, its a beautiful day.. I just solved that issue too..

Comment: Hi , remember to mark the answer when you have time , it will help others who have similar issue. :-)